# how '.join()' worked in below Python code

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

There're two dataframes 'left' and 'right'. I'm applying '.join' on dataframes, changing default value of parameters 'how' and 'on'. I'm not able to understand on what logic/how I am getting the below outcome.

```
import pandas as pd
left = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2'],
                     'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2']},
                      index=['K0', 'K1', 'K2']) 

right = pd.DataFrame({'C': ['C0', 'C2', 'C3'],
                    'D': ['D0', 'D2', 'D3']},
                      index=['K0', 'K2', 'K3'])

left.join(right,how='outer',on='A')
```

actual output:

```
    A   B   C   D
K0  A0  B0  NaN NaN
K1  A1  B1  NaN NaN
K2  A2  B2  NaN NaN
K2  K0  NaN C0  D0
K2  K2  NaN C2  D2
K2  K3  NaN C3  D3
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this output since you are specifying that the `.join` should be on column named `A`, which is not existent in the `right` DataFrame.

The `on` parameter should be a Column or index level name to join on the index of the other `DataFrame`, in your case, since `A` is not the index of the other DataFrame, there is no join happening, just concatenating the two dataframes based on the `outer` join.

Instead, you shouldn't use `on` since `.join` uses `index` by default.

```
import pandas as pd
left = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2'],
                     'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2']},
                      index=['K0', 'K1', 'K2']) 

right = pd.DataFrame({'C': ['C0', 'C2', 'C3'],
                    'D': ['D0', 'D2', 'D3']},
                      index=['K0', 'K2', 'K3'])

left.join(right,how='outer')
```

```
    A   B   C   D
K0  A0  B0  C0  D0
K1  A1  B1  NaN NaN 
K2  A2  B2  C2  D2
K3  NaN NaN C3  D3
```

If you would like to merge based on values in a column, use [`pd.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) instead.

Comment: I know `on` parameter should be on a Column or index level name and I'm providing column name which doesn't exist on right df (that's intentionally done).
But I wanted to know how python filters/process output for this `left.join(right,how='outer',on='A')`. Moreover it want not just concatenation because the indexes of resultant df contains 'K2' 4 times, which doesn't happen in concatenation.